# Run code after all EF Core migrations are applied

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

EF Core 5 has various [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/events), but they relate to `DbContext`. There are no events related to migrations (`Migration`).

I want to run custom code after all migrations are applied - whether triggered by code (`context.Database.Migrate()`) or the CLI (`dotnet ef database update`).

The workaround is to add an "empty" migration, and place my code in its `Up` method. But I would need to do that every time I add a migration.

Assuming there's no event or hook I can use (is there?), how can I run custom code after all migrations are applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround.

```cs
[DbContext(typeof(MyContext))]
[Migration("99999999999999_Last1")]
public class Last1 : Migration {
  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
    Task.Run(() => callPostMigrationCodeThatIsIdempotent()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    migrationBuilder.DeleteData(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, nameof(HistoryRow.MigrationId), "string", "99999999999999_Last2", null);
  }
}

[DbContext(typeof(MyContext))]
[Migration("99999999999999_Last2")]
public class Last2 : Migration {
  protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
    Task.Run(() => callPostMigrationCodeThatIsIdempotent()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    migrationBuilder.DeleteData(HistoryRepository.DefaultTableName, nameof(HistoryRow.MigrationId), "string", "99999999999999_Last1", null);
  }
}
```

There are two "last" migrations:

- their ids are chosen so they run last ("99999999999999")
- both call the custom code, which **must** be idempotent
- each deletes the other from the history table
- they use `Task.Run` for async over sync

During each run one or the other runs the custom code, and deletes the other from the history table. On the next run the opposite would occur.

The same double setup can be used for a pre-migration hook.

There's an open backlog item on the [repo](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24710).